# How do I pass content to a side bar from a page in django?

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I'm building a website in Django, and I want to have the main navbar and a side for finer detail.

I'm happy to hardcode the main navbar, but I'd like the sidebar to reflect the sections in the page (with anchor links to each).

I've seen mention of [`{{block.super}}`](https://gist.github.com/issackelly/928783) but that example is a little to abstract for me to understand how to apply it to my situation.

This is my [sidebar](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/):

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                Website Title.
            </a>
        </li>
        {%for section in page%}
        <li>
            <a href="#{{section.name}}">{{section.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Do I need to extend this in my base.html? Or Do I extend my page template?

This is the body of my current base.html:

```
<body>
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm a little lost as how to implement this into my app. How should I be passing the content of my subpage into the navbar?

Comment: When I understand your question well, there is no need to include the sidebar in your template. I think you just need two forloops in your template. One forloop for your links, and one for your sections. BTW: you are missing an endfor tag in your code.

Comment: @het.oosten What else do you need to know? I'm trying to stay DRY as I'll be repeating the code otherwise.

Comment: I think it is fine to do two forloops in this case, because they have a different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a different content block for the navbar in your base.html and override the block in your following templates file.

Comment: How would I 'override' the block?

Comment: The guy here http://www.anton-pirker.at/django-override-block-that-was-included-in-parent-template/ has explained it better with an e.g,might be of your help.